# How to copy a cell & paste it to multiple cells in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to copy the amount and paste it to all empty cells above the amount [as shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfK8X.png) , using VBA or Macro in MS Excel

Edit:
This is what I done it.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("F5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F2:F4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F8:F11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

This code only works on this table only. If contents change it's not working. eg: if more items added, it's giving different outputs.

Can anyone help me to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post any code you've tried thusfar; this site is for collaboration, not a code-for-you service.

Comment: @Cyril please see edit. I think my code is completely wrong that's why I didn't post it initially.

Comment: Ok, so looking at what you're doing in the code you have a few pieces going on, which can be solved with a loop... let's start from the BOTTOM of your table; you will want to DYNAMICALLY determine the last row ("LR").  Rob de Bruin has a great outline of how to do this (google that shit).  From there, you can use a for loop and if-statement to copy the content from LR to 1 Step -1.  Please take some time and try to build code with that information, then we can correct the more specific issues you have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as the logic of the copying of values, I think this is something you need to work out. But I do have some hints of how to get there.

Do **NOT** use Select/Copy/Paste - Use direct assignment instead

```
Range("G5").Resize(3, 1).Value = Range("F5").Value
```

This will take the one value in cell `F5` and use it to assign the three cells `G5:G7`.

To pick a specific value in a table, use the `.Cells()` function

```
For i=1 to 10
  Range("B2").Cells(i,1).Value = Range("A2").Cells(i,1).Value
Next i
```

To count the number of rows down, or column across that have values use the following functions (placed in a module).

```
Public Function CountCols(ByVal r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountCols = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(0, 1)) Then
        CountCols = 1
    Else
        CountCols = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    End If
End Function

Public Function CountRows(ByVal r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```

To be used as

```
Dim n as Long
' Count rows in table starting from A2
n = CountRows(Range("A2"))
Dim r as Range
' Set a range reference to n×1 cells under A2
Set r = Range("A2").Resize(n,1)
```

To check if a cell is empty, use `IsEmpty()` just like I have used in `CountRows()`.

Can **you** piece all these pieces together to make a macro that does what you want? You should: a) check how many rows are in the table, b) go down the cells and check if they are empty in the destination and c) if they are, copy from the same row in the source.